# React app: Calling arrow function from arrow function ONLY in production causes error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got an issue in an application I'm building that I've simplified by reproducing in a brand new app created by create-react-app.

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import TheComponent from "./component";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <TheComponent />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

component.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TheComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  ErrorMessage = ({ title, error }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <strong>{title}</strong>
        <br />
        {error}
      </div>
    );
  };

  ForgotForm = () => {
    return <this.ErrorMessage title="TITLE" error="error message" />;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <this.ForgotForm />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default TheComponent;
```

This all works absolutely PERFECT when in local development. But when I run "npm run build", it doesn't matter where that build is hosted, the page goes completely blank, and the javascript console shows this error:

[image]

Links to: [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args%5B%5D=undefined&args%5B%5D=)

Which says the error is: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

Comment: `ErrorMessage` looks like a standalone component, why is it defined internally? Also, while I'm not sure if it's completely invalid syntax, it's certainly very uncommon to use `this.forgotForm` in JSX, it doesn't follow ***any*** React naming and usage conventions, and thus likely isn't being interpreted as a react component. See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with this:https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized
try renaming it to `ForgotForm`?

I also haven't seen components be defined like this `<this.forgotForm />`, is there a benefit over just invoking the function `{forgotForm()}`

Comment: I totally made that change after I noticed the inconsistency after posting. Same behavior.

These are just functional components within the class. If the ErrorMessage functional component were in a different file, I could call it with <ErrorMessage>. I went through and switched from calling with JSX to calling how you point out {this.ErrorMessage()} and the error is gone. Question is, is that a bug? calling <ForgotForm /> works fine, but when I add the call to <ErrorMessage /> in ForgotForm, that's when the error shows.

Comment: I believe since the JSX will be translated to `React.createElement(this.ErrorMessage, ...)`, the context of `this` isn't your class. but I could be wrong